# how to place the view div from bottom to top

Tags: php, html, css

I just learned coding world,,,, need some help please,,,
I want to make a display like this picture ..,
[image]
but I really don't know how ... I use br, but when it is applied to the mobile version, it gets messy,,,,
or can "while" or "do" make it look like in the picture ??
please help

this is my messy script

```css
.crop {
  width: 9%;
  height: auto;
  border:5px double;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 0px 20px;
  float:left;
  margin:0.3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="crop">24</div>
<div class="crop">23</div>
<div class="crop">22</div>
<div class="crop">21</div>
<div class="crop">20</div>
<div class="crop">19</div>
<br><br>
<div class="crop">18</div>
<div class="crop">17</div>
<div class="crop">16</div>
<div class="crop">15</div>
<div class="crop">14</div>
<div class="crop">13</div>
<div class="crop">12</div>
<div class="crop">11</div>
<div class="crop">10</div>
<br><br>
<div class="crop">9</div>
<div class="crop">8</div>
<div class="crop">7</div>
<div class="crop">6</div>
<div class="crop">5</div>
<div class="crop">4</div>
<div class="crop">3</div>
<div class="crop">2</div>
<div class="crop">1</div>
```

Comment: unsure how you expect it to show up on a mobile browser since screen is small....

Comment: Why is this tagged as php?

Comment: bcause ill use while or for soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what how it is supposed to behave on mobile. Are you looking for something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>

<style>
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
.crop {
    width: 9%;
    height: auto;
    border:5px double;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 0px 20px;
    margin:0.3%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="crop">24</div>
    <div class="crop">23</div>
    <div class="crop">22</div>
    <div class="crop">21</div>
    <div class="crop">20</div>
    <div class="crop">19</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="crop">18</div>
    <div class="crop">17</div>
    <div class="crop">16</div>
    <div class="crop">15</div>
    <div class="crop">14</div>
    <div class="crop">13</div>
    <div class="crop">12</div>
    <div class="crop">11</div>
    <div class="crop">10</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```